# Как добавить свой html в структуру Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Мне необходимо на странице каждого поста над заголовком h1 вывести div с картинкой. Для этого я попробовал использовать js

```
(function($) {
"use strict"
if($('body').hasClass('single-post') ) {
    var imgURL = 'http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/picture.jpg';
    var container = '<div class="circle_photo">';
        container += '<img src="'+imgURL+'" alt="picture">';
        container += '</div>';
    $('.post').append(container);
}})(jQuery);
```

Однако, желаемого результата добиться не получилось. Вероятно, я где-то допустил ошибку или существуют иные способы?

Comment: Странный код, но он работает ( https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/un24da5q/ ). Может вы не подключили jQuery... ? `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: В папке темы найдите файл `single.php` и там пропишите свою разметку.

Comment: Обычно такие вещи решаются хуками в теме. У вас какая тема?